# accent mark question about american names

Tags: accent

ok what accent mark should be on the name chloe for an american, e, è, é, ê, ë? I am an argument with a peer and would like some outside opinions. Please help

Comment: In America, you can spell your name however you want.

Comment: It's in the Constitution, as my friend Jönnnn told me.

Comment: The one I have seen (besides Chloe) is Chloë.  I am afraid that however she wants it spelled, it will be written Chloe by most people in the US despite her wishes.

Comment: ... but after Brexit, all graves, acutes ... must be left at immigration in the UK. Or down the café.

Comment: I know a woman called Dea and here (UK) she struggles to stop people calling her "Dee".

Comment: Regardless of how Chloë chooses to write her name, in most US usage, the diacritic marks will generally be dispensed with, and it will almost universally appear as ***Chloe***. I wouldn't stress out about it...

Answer (score 4):

The diaresis or tréma (*not* an umlaut), over the 'e' in given names like Chloë, Zoë, or Noël, is used to inform or remind the reader that the 'e' is a separate syllable, so that they do not rhyme with 'hoe', 'toe', or 'Joe'. It is seen in the surname of the Brontë sisters, who were 19th century English writers. Their father changed it from Brunty, some say, to disguise his humble background. It is a matter of style, and if the correct way to pronounce those names is widely known, then a diaresis is often considered unnecessary, or, possibly, affected.

The diaresis is old-fashioned, verging on archaic, in British English, but held out longer in the USA, notably in the *New Yorker*, but even there its usefulness is in doubt. Allegedly the style editor of that publication said in 1978 that he was thinking of changing the style guidance to remove it, but 'then he died and nobody has dared bring it up since':

> The fact is that, absent the two dots, most people would not trip over
>   the “coop” in “cooperate” or the “reel” in “reelect” (though they
>   might pronounce the “zoo” in “zoological,” a potential application of
>   the diaeresis that we get no credit for resisting). And yet we use the
>   diaeresis for the same reason that we use the hyphen: to keep the cow
>   out of co-workers.
>
> Basically, we have three options for these kinds of words:
>   “cooperate,” “co-operate,” and “coöperate.” Back when the magazine was
>   just getting started, someone decided that the first misread and the
>   second was ridiculous, and adopted the diaeresis as the most elegant
>   solution with the broadest application.

[The Curse of the Diaeresis](https://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/the-curse-of-the-diaeresis)

As for the others, mainly found in French loan words, è (e grave), is used in French within a word to make the vowel flat (like in set, pet, or met), é (e acute) is used to make it rhyme with hay, way, tray, etc, ê (e circonflexe) does not change the pronunciation but compensates for a dropped following 's' in modern French (dropped from the Old French spelling, I mean).

Comment: I am currently listening, during my commute, to an audiobook about nuclear accidents, read by an American, and I noticed that he first of all said 'reagent' as I would expect (re - agent), but since about a quarter of the way through, he has been saying saying 'reegent'.